# How do I combine two columns with offset data?

Tags: r, multiple-columns

My dataset contains two columns with data that are offset - something like:

```
col1<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND")
col2<-c("ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "e", "f", "g", "h")
dataset<-data.frame(cbind(col1, col2))
```

I would like to combine those two offset columns into a single column that contains the letters a through h and nothing else.

Something like the following is what I'm thinking, but rbind is not the right command:

```
dataset$combine<-rbind(dataset$col1[1:4], dataset$col2[5:8])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
sel2 <- col2!="ND"
col1[sel2] <- col2[sel2]
> col1
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
```

Comment: This is great Ari - thanks.  The problem is that my actual dataset (this is obv. a sample) has missing data scattered throughout col1 and col2, so this code would eliminate those rows too, which I don't want to do - I want to keep all rows.  Is there some way I could instead use the row numbers, as I attempted to do in the example using rbind? Thanks again.

Comment: @Luke, you may want to consider converting `"ND"` to actual `NA` values when reading your data into R.

Comment: Fundamentally you can achieve what you want by some combination of logical vectors.  Look at `help("&")` and `help("|")`.  And consider And consider @AnandaMahto's suggestion to use `NA`'s, although then you have to use `is.na` rather than `==`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sapply` and an anonymous function:

```
dataset[sapply(dataset, function(x) x != "ND")]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
dataset$combine <- dataset[sapply(dataset, function(x) x != "ND")]
dataset
#   col1 col2 combine
# 1    a   ND       a
# 2    b   ND       b
# 3    c   ND       c
# 4    d   ND       d
# 5   ND    e       e
# 6   ND    f       f
# 7   ND    g       g
# 8   ND    h       h
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep` to find the matching elements and select them:

```
c(col1[grep("^[a-h]$",col1)],col2[grep("^[a-h]$",col2)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way, using `mapply` and `gsub`:

```
 within(dataset, combine <- mapply(gsub, pattern='ND', replacement=col2, x=col1))
#   col1 col2 combine
# 1    a   ND       a
# 2    b   ND       b
# 3    c   ND       c
# 4    d   ND       d
# 5   ND    e       e
# 6   ND    f       f
# 7   ND    g       g
# 8   ND    h       h
```

Per your comment to @Andrie's answer, this will also preserve `NA` rows.

Answer (score 1):

Another point of view:

```
transform(dataset, 
          combine=dataset[apply(dataset, 2, function(x) x %in% letters[1:8])])
  col1 col2 combine
1    a   ND       a
2    b   ND       b
3    c   ND       c
4    d   ND       d
5   ND    e       e
6   ND    f       f
7   ND    g       g
8   ND    h       h

dataset$combine <- dataset[apply(dataset,2, function(x) nchar(x)==1)] #Also works
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is to think simple enough... ;-)

```
dataset$combine<-c(dataset$col1[1:4], dataset$col2[5:8])
```

Comment: @Morten His `col1` and `col2` are probably `factor`s...and maybe you have `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` set by default?